# How to move file from one directory to another within same FTP using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using SSH SFTP Sampler for sftp testing in jmeter. I am able to get/Put files from Ftp location to local location and vice versa. But I am not able to move file form one directory to another in same FTP location.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) and [Apache Commons FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for this.

FTPClient has [rename(from, to)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#rename(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method which can be used for moving files around your FTP server.

Example code:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("your FTP server address");
client.login("username", "password");   

client.rename("folder1/file1.txt", "folder2/file1.txt");
client.logout();
client.disconnect();
```

For more information on enhancing your test with scripting check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.